# How To Apply This Boost ASIO Example To My Application

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've been reading a lot of ASIO examples, but I'm still sort of confused on how to use them in my application.

Basically, my server side needs to accept more than 100 connections (clients), this part is done by using a pool of threads (usually, 2~4 threads for each CPU core).

For simplicity, let's just assume there is only one connection.

For simplicity, I would also like to copy the example from: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/nonblocking/third_party_lib.cpp

```
class session
{
public:
    session(tcp::socket&)
    bool want_read() const;
    bool do_read(boost::system::error_code&);
    bool want_write() const;
    bool do_write(boost::system::error_code&);
};

class connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<connection> pointer;
    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service&);
    tcp::socket& socket();
    void start();
private:
    connection(boost::asio::io_service&);
    void start_operation();
    void handle_read(boost::system::error_code);
    void handle_write(boost::system::error_code);
}

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service&, unsigned short);
private:
    void start_accept();
    void handle_accept(connection::pointer, const boost::system::error_code&);
}
```

You can check the link for the complete class implementations.

What I'm trying to do is to add for read/write operations into class `session` (or should I directly put them in `connection`?)

```
AsyncRead(buffer, expectedBytesToRead, timeout, handler);
Read(buffer, expectedBytesToRead, timeout);
AsyncWrite(buffer, expectedBytesToWrite, timeout, handler);
Write(buffer, expectedBytesToWrite, timeout);
```

I did read a lot of examples, but it seems to me that it's very difficult to figure out how to use them, i.e., implement the above 4 common methods in my application.

I guess I'm very close to what I want, I just don't where to start from a very simple example.  The example I read @ boost.org, they are either too complicated to figure out the logic or not what I want in my project.

Comment: the `null_buffers` example you linked to shows how to integrate the asio `io_service` event loop with a library that already performs `read` and `write` on the socket. It's not clear to me you have that requirement. Can you clarify why you want to use `null_buffers`?

Comment: Yes.  I'm also confused.  The reason I did this is I want to separate the reading/writing logic from the `connection` class.  Maybe, as I said, I should just put the above 4 requested methods in `connection` class (removing the useless `session` class)?  Another reason is, I have an old class (from my old code) doing the low-level reading/writing operations, so I'm treating it as a third-party-lib.

Comment: since it's your code I advise you to rewrite it using Asio's `async_read()` and `async_write()` free functions. The only reason to use `null_buffers` is if you have legacy code or third party code that cannot possibly be changed.

Comment: @Sam: OK, I'll just remove all of my old code doing reading/writing operations.  But I'm still unclear on how to plug in the above 4 methods I need.  All the examples from boost.org are to simply send the message back (or after some processing) to the client upon receiving some data from the client.

Comment: Asio is very flexible in what you can do, and without an idea what exactly what you're having problem with it's very difficult to help you. For instance, what are your clients doing? Only talking to the server or to each other? Are they requesting data or sending data or both? Could you give an idea what you're trying to do? For inter-client comminucation, the chat server example is pretty good. The HTTP server examples are good to see how a pure client-server communication works.

Comment: As you're in control over all implementation, what Sam is suggesting makes sense. Also take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039057/boost-asio-for-sync-server-keeping-tcp-session-open-with-google-proto-buffers/7044160#7044160) for a simple description what is in the chat server example.

Comment: @TomKerr What would you choose to use instead?

Comment: @Dronz I came to terms with it.  boost.asio is worth learning and using, though the documentation still sucked last I looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping all of your communication with the socket in your connection class, keeping it as generic as possible.

Your options are almost limitless on how you want to do it.  What I do is pass a shared_ptr of my "Message Handling" class to each new Connection and also create a Session like you do, but I pass a copy of each Connection to the Session and all relevant info as well..  so each individual session can notify the program when a new message comes in, and I can store anything else I want in each Session.

Just be careful about notifying your Sessions when the Connection terminates, since you are now storing it somewhere and not only keeping the smart pointer alive via call-backs.

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<class Connection> connectionPtr;

void Server::handle_accept(sessionPtr new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
if (!error)
{
   cout << "New connection detected." << endl;
   string sessionID = misc::generateSessionID();
   string IPaddress = new_connection->socket().remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
   mSessionManager_->AddSession(new_connection, IPaddress, sessionID);
   // session manager now has a copy of the connection and
   //  can reference this by the sessioNID or IPAddress
   new_connection->start();

   connectionPtr NEWER_CONNECTION(new Connection(_io_service, _loginList, _mMessageHandlerClass));

   cout << "Awaiting next connection..." << endl;
   acceptor_.async_accept(newer_session->socket(),
   boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, NEWER_CONNECTION, 
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
else
{
  new_connection.reset();
}
```

}

Here's just an example of how to handle a message.  Obviously totalbytesremaining needs to be extracted from the header, which I didn't include in examples.

```
void Session::handle_body(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
if(!error)
    {
        totalBytesRemaining -= bytes_transferred;

        if (totalBytesRemaining == 0)
            {
            if (incompleteToggle = true)
            {
                tempMessage+=string(readMsg.body());
                messageHandlerClass->Process(sessionID,tempMessage);
                tempMessage = "";
                tempMessageToggle = false;
            }
            else
            {
                tempMessage += string(readMsg.body());
                std::cout << "Incomplete receive:  This is our message So far.\n\n" << tempMessage << "\n" << endl;
                tempMessageToggle = true;
            }

        }

    handle_message();
    }
else
{
    removeSession();
}
```

So now I have access to all my Sessions from the SessionManager class

```
void SessionManager::listConnectedIP()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sessionBox.size(); x++)
    {
        cout << sessionBox[x]->IPaddress() << endl;
    }
}
void SessionManager::massSendMessage(const std::string &message)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sessionBox.size(); x++)
    {
        sessionBox[x]->connectionPtr->pushMessage(message);
    }
}
```

And the Connection class for handling messages is something like this.  Message just holds the buffer and encodes and decodes the header.  It's another modified class I found on the boost example website.

```
void Connection::pushMessage(const string& message)
{
 // boost async_write will return instantly, but guarantees to
 // either error or send all requested bytes.
 // there is no need to check if all bytes get sent in the callback.
    Message writeMsg;
    writeMsg.body_length( strlen(msg.c_str()) );
    memcpy( writeMsg.body(), msg.c_str(), writeMsg.body_length() );
    writeMsg.encode_header();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(writeMsg.data(), writeMsg.length()),
    boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Sorry if my examples aren't very good.  To get a real grasp of boost::asio and their examples, you really need to understand how asynchronous functions and callbacks work.